# Preview search not highlighting instances of the word

Tags: preview, search

I am using OSX Catalina. However, for quite some time, do not remember from which OSX, Preview stopped highlighting instances of a searched for word.  As suggested in the answer to the post [Preview does not find words correctly](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/277641/preview-does-not-find-words-correctly?rq=1), if I choose `Table of Contents' in View, the sections of pages where the searched for word appears are displayed in the sidebar but the word is not highlighted. Also, in the top right corner of the Preview window, below the search box, there are two arrows to go forward/backward through the search results. These arrows remain greyed out and do not work. These issues are rather irksome. Is there any way out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preview: PDF Highlighting & Search Stop Working until Restart](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/375716/preview-pdf-highlighting-search-stop-working-until-restart)

Comment: Yes, thank you. It does. I normally upgraded to macOS 10.15.2 today and after that saw the link shared by you. Lo and behold! Things are working fine.